# UITableViewCell's custom selectedBackgroundView with round corners

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-view

I have designed my Custom TableViewCell which has custom selectedBackgroundView+ some other features.
**Issue:**
 In TableView 'Grouped' Style, First & Last Cell should have round corners on selection. How to achieve round corners for first and last cells.

[image]

**Code:** MNATableViewCell is inherited from UITableViewCell

```
@implementation MNATableViewCell

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if(customSelectedBackgroundView==nil)
    {
        customSelectedBackgroundView = [MNATableViewCell getCellSelectedBackgroundView];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = customSelectedBackgroundView;
    }
}

+ (UIView*) getCellSelectedBackgroundView
{
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bg-cell-active.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

    [imageView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

    [imageView setFrame:bgView.frame];
    [bgView addSubview:imageView];
    [bgView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [bgView sizeToFit];
    return bgView;
}
@end
```